# Формат вывода числа в System.out.printf

Tags: java

Например, я хочу, чтобы число занимало 10 символов (%10d) и при любом обстоятельстве состояло из 3 цифр(%03d). Так вот, как мне совместить эти две операции?

Comment: я имел ввиду, как это должно выглядеть? `.......003`, где `.` - пробел?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделали из двух частей, как Вы в принципе и думали.

```
System.out.printf("%7s", String.format("%03d", 22));
//     022
```

Либо, чтобы удобнее было указать промежутки:

```
int l = 7, n = 2;
System.out.printf("%" + l + "s", String.format("%0" + n + "d", 2));
//      02
```

Answer (score 1):

Настраиваемая длина:

```
static String getFormatNumber(int number, int zeros, int spaced) {
    String zerosNumber = String.format("%0" + zeros + "d", number);
    return String.format("%" + spaced + "s", zerosNumber);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(getFormatNumber(12, 3, 10));
    //        012

    System.out.println(getFormatNumber(12, 5, 10));
    //      00012
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю как-то так

```
System.out.printf("       %03d");
```

10 символов последние %03d

Или по другому

```
String empty = " ";
empty = empty.repeat(7);

System.out.printf(empty+ "%03d", 3);
```